# How to display newly added attributes in magento?

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I added a new attribute in `Magento`.

```
 Attribute Label -> Weight Available 
 Attribute code -> weight_multi
 input type -> multiple select 
 values are -> 1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5
```

Now I want to `echo` the `Weight Available` attribute in page.

To display `Name` of the product we can use `echo $_product->getName();`

How to display `Weight Available` attribute?

`$_product` object contain all product details.

But when I try

`var_dump($_product->weight_multi);` This gives

```
string(26) "30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22"
```

This is strange the expected value is `1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5`.
How can I resolve this?? And how to display the newly added attribute in page by  code.

I tried `echo $_product->getWeight_multi();`. But no luck..

I am using **Magento 1.9.0.1**.

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

You can print value like this :

```
print_r($_product->getWeightMulti());
```

if you want to display attribute in product page. the go to admin panel -> catalog -> attributes ->manage attributes -> select your attribute to edit

there you will find "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end"  set to yes then it will be displayed in product page.

check also in admin panel if there is any warning then refresh index and refresh cache.

Comment: @ saumik, thanks for your reply. print_r($_product->getWeightMulti()); prints 30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22. The expected values are 1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5. But I don't know why this prints like this...

Comment: print_r($_product->getSku());  check sku is ok ?  in which you have added this attribute value?

Answer (score 1):

> You have to either add the attribute to your collection filter or load each product so you have access to all of its attributes:

```
require_once( 'app/Mage.php' );

umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$sCustomerId = 1;
$oQuotes = Mage::getModel( 'sales/quote' )->getCollection();
$oQuotes->addFieldToFilter( 'customer_id', $sCustomerId );
foreach( $oQuotes as $oQuote )
{
    var_dump( $oQuote->getId() );
    var_dump( $oQuote->getData( 'customer_email' ) );
    var_dump( $oQuote->getData( 'customer_id' ) );

    $oItems = Mage::getModel( 'sales/quote_item' )
        ->getCollection()
        ->setQuote( $oQuote );
    foreach( $oItems as $oItem )
    {
        $oProduct = $oItem->getProduct();
        $oProductModel = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )->load( $oProduct->getId() );
        $sWeight = $oProductModel->getData( 'weight_multi' );
        var_dump( $sWeight );
        $sFormat  = $oProductModel->getAttributeText( 'weight_multi' );
        var_dump( $sFormat );
    }
}
```